# how to find the last modifed file with wild card matching in a directory in C++

Tags: c++, windows, file, mingw

How can one find the latest file like *.csv (or some other wild card matching pattern in file name) in a directory based on last modifed time in C++? Assuming using mingw gcc under windows?

Since this is a one line command like

```
dir /o:-d *.csv
```

I currently use `_popen()` to call the system command above and extract the results. I was wondering if there is a better alternative to the `popen` solution to it.

Comment: Are you asking how to read a directory, or how to identify the most recent file once you have read the directory? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Treat this as a two-part problem: finding files with the correct extension, then inspecting the last modified time with [stat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_(system_call)). Then show what you got.

Comment: Actually, forget about `stat` (unless you want a function that can work without Windows). As usual in Windows, [there is an API for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364418(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Windows API which provides a set of directory search functions.  When using the directory search you specify a file search criteria and then do repeated calls until there are no more files or you have found the one you want.

The nice thing about these functions is that as part of returning the next file in the directory, there is also returned a struct containing various file attributes including the date and time stamps as well as whether the file is hidden or not.

So you could use a loop something like the following source code snip:

```
WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;
uInt2++;
TCHAR *ptcsFileNameEnd = tcsFileName + _tcslen(tcsFileName);

_tcscat (ptcsFileNameEnd, _T("\\*.*"));
memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));
HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile(tcsFileName, &search_data);

while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    if ((search_data.dwFileAttributes & (FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM | FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN)) == 0) {
        *(ptcsFileNameEnd + 1) = 0;
        _tcscat (ptcsFileNameEnd, search_data.cFileName);
        if (ReadAndProcessLicenseFile (tcsFileName)) {
            uInt2 = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
}
```

In your case you would look at the search_data struct for the date time stamp and do comparisons.

**EDIT**
The struct WIN32_FIND_DATA is defined in winbase.h and the struct looks like the following for my Visual Studio C++ 2005 environment with UNICODE turned on.

```
typedef struct _WIN32_FIND_DATAW {
    DWORD dwFileAttributes;
    FILETIME ftCreationTime;
    FILETIME ftLastAccessTime;
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;
    DWORD nFileSizeHigh;
    DWORD nFileSizeLow;
    DWORD dwReserved0;
    DWORD dwReserved1;
    WCHAR  cFileName[ MAX_PATH ];
    WCHAR  cAlternateFileName[ 14 ];
#ifdef _MAC
    DWORD dwFileType;
    DWORD dwCreatorType;
    WORD  wFinderFlags;
#endif
} WIN32_FIND_DATAW, *PWIN32_FIND_DATAW, *LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW;
#ifdef UNICODE
typedef WIN32_FIND_DATAW WIN32_FIND_DATA;
typedef PWIN32_FIND_DATAW PWIN32_FIND_DATA;
typedef LPWIN32_FIND_DATAW LPWIN32_FIND_DATA;
#else
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows, you can use `GetFileTime()` Api. In linux, `fstat()` can help you.